# C++ "delete" is slow. Where should I look first?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a C++ application where the "delete" function is slow to run. What might cause this and where should I begin my search for a solution?

**Background:**

This C++ code is in an ARX file running inside of AutoCAD, which is basically just a DLL.

The specific computer where delete is slow is running AutoCAD 2011, Windows 7, 64-bit. ARX's for AutoCAD 2011 have to be compiled using Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1.

The computer with the problem is a customer's computer. It does not have any version of Visual Studio installed on it.

On my development computer, the code does not have any problem in AutoCAD 2011.

To test, I have some code that deletes a linked list. On the computer with the problem, it takes 0.7 seconds to delete the list. On the computers and configurations without the problem, the same code takes 0.02 seconds. The specific times are not important--the large different between the two numbers is.

I made sure to be running the same version of the code on both computers, so it is not a release versus debug build problem.

Comment: How many items were in the list, and what was their size?

Comment: Share the test code you are using for benchmark.

Comment: And are you statically/dynamically linking on both systems? And please confirm you are not comparing debug/release builds?

Comment: The numbers given indicates very large datasets. Host OS memory management will most definitely come into play. Even 0.02 seconds for a delete seems very high.

Comment: Are you sure you are not comparing debug and release versions? Difference is 35 times!

Comment: I've added updates to the question in response to the comments. And yes, linked-lists are yuck, but that's what the AutoCAD libraries use for passing data, so it's what I get to deal with.

Comment: If you're concerned about speed, you might as well delete the line `head->resval.rstring = NULL;` But of course this code should not take 0.7 seconds, whether debug or release.

Comment: You need to get a profiler up on the problem computer, either intrusively (in the program) or with an external program. Either way, it's no use benchmarking a fake program, especially a hand-written implementation of `std::list` and `std::string`, which you should be using. (Of course, `std::list` is arguably the worse container, but it does demonstrate the `delete` problem, if that's actually the problem.)

Comment: I had small app that calculated prime numbers and it was slow when I build it with VS2008sp1 and more than twice faster when I build it with VS2005 (both in release mode). My problem was also related with allocating and deleteting, but I didn't find the reason of such big difference between binary compiled with 2 version of VC++... I would like to know the answer as well :)

Comment: Based upon Peterchen's suggestion, I used PerfMon to check for page faults. My computer has 0 when idling. The problem computer had 100k / second when idling! I'm pretty sure that's the problem.

Comment: @David Robison: A custom allocator - arena or pool - might help in that case.

Comment: Finally found the source of all these page faults: the Windows Search service. Disabled that, the page fault total went down to 3,000 / second, and everything runs great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly in the order I'd check them:

- **Other plugins:** could that behavior caused by other ARX files? Can they be disabled on bad system?
- **PerfMon:** Check if  soft/hard page faults or cache misses peak during your delete (I hope you can set that up on the customers computer).
- **HeapQueryInformation:** same values in good/bad environment?
- **Heap Lock**: Could some other thread be highly active in the background, holding tight to the heap's lock? You could test by wrapping the loop in HeapLock / HeapUnlock (and time inside the lock, of course).
- **Hooks:** Could the respective code be hooked? (e.g. a 3rd party app hooking into the C++/Win32 Heap functions to do whatever it wants to do)
- **Grasping at straws:** Do the respective `new`'s take unusually long? How are the individual  `delete` times distributed?

Answer (score 1):

Could be due to different cache efficiency between the working/failing system.  There may be more memory fragmentation on the failing system which causes the large delete to thrash the cache.  On a quiescent system the data may end up more sequential and get more cache hits during the big delete.

Try the Intel Performance Counter Monitor?

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable and possible, then try to use a profiler on the customer's computer.

You may try [AMD CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/cpu/codeanalyst/Pages/default.aspx) or the Intel profiler (though that one is not free).

If that is not possible, then add profiling code to your release builds and gather results from the customer. Even simple profiling code may help you find the real bottleneck.

It does not look like the delete itself is the problem, but the problem may be some other part of the code.

E.g. - what is the type of `head->resval.rstring` ?

Answer (score 0):

We run into this all the time. It's nothing wrong with your code, deleting thousands of items can take several seconds (and I've seen it reach minutes, too) even in Release mode.

The answer is to not delete. Get yourself a real memory allocator, and instead of individually allocating each object create a memory pool (or a custom heap or whatever you want to call it). [Nedmalloc](https://github.com/ned14/nedmalloc) is what we use and recommend, and you can create a "nedpool." Basically, a pool is a block of memory where your objects will be allocated from. You still allocate memory for each object, but it gets taken from the pool rather than directly from the OS.

When the time to delete comes, you just delete the entire pool rather than deleting the objects one by one. Use a different pool for each batch of objects that will expire at the same time. You do not need to allocate memory for the whole pool upfront, but you can only delete the whole thing at once.

Comment: Most C++ objects have undefined behavior if you do this. You at least need to arrange for the destructors of the contained objects to be called.

Comment: Of course. You need to use in-place new and then manually call the destructor yourself, but do not deallocate the memory.

Answer (score 0):

How is the retlist being generated?  Additionally, Is there a reason you are allocating and deleting the resbufs manually instead of using acutNewRb and acutRelRb?

Also, you have probably checked these, but does the user have the default drawing loaded in both AutoCAD 2009 and 2011? If not, are the drawings the same (except for ACAD version), and are they located locally, or on a network drive? You might also look at whether the user has the same lisp/.Net/objectARX applications running in both instances.  Also, is the AutoCAD 2011 a network or local installation?

Finally, you might want to add autocad and objectarx tags to the question.

Comment: retList is being generated using acutBuildList. I was using acutRelRb to release the memory, but while profiling the code, I found that function to be the problem. I rewrote it manually both to see if that would fix the problem (it didn't) and so that I would have a better idea of what was causing the problem. In all cases I am running the code on the same drawing.